# angularjs daterangepicker not populating ngmodel

Tags: javascript, angularjs, daterangepicker

I'm trying to use http://www.daterangepicker.com/ with angularjs but I cannot get the value of ngModel updated. I have written the following directive but can anyone please tell me why scope.ngModel is always undefined?

```
angular.module('daterangepickerDirective', [])
.directive('daterangepicker', function() {

    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            ngModel: '='
        },          
        link: function( scope, element, attrs ) {
            console.log('scope.ngModel') // UNDEFINED. Why?
            // Date range picker
            element.daterangepicker({
                locale: {
                    format: 'YYYY-MM-DD',
                    showDropdowns: true
                },
                ranges: {
                   'All Time': ['1900-01-01', moment()],
                   'Today': [moment(), moment()],
                   'Yesterday': [moment().subtract(1, 'days'), moment().subtract(1, 'days')],
                   'Last 7 Days': [moment().subtract(6, 'days'), moment()],
                   'Last 30 Days': [moment().subtract(29, 'days'), moment()],
                   'This Month': [moment().startOf('month'), moment().endOf('month')],
                   'Last Month': [moment().subtract(1, 'month').startOf('month'), moment().subtract(1, 'month').endOf('month')]
                }                   
            }).on("apply.daterangepicker",function(event){
                scope.$apply(function() {
                   scope.ngModel.$setViewValue(event.date);//This will update the model property bound to your ng-model whenever the datepicker's date changes.
                });
            });             
        }
    }
});
```

My HTML is simply

```
<input type="text" daterangepicker class="form-control" ng-model="selected_filters.date" />
```

Many thanks.

Comment: One thing that stands out is that your directive's scope uses an attribute named `ngModel` ... That is most likely going to conflict w/the `ng-model` directive. In the HTML, how does Angular know if you want the ng-model directive, or if you want to pass a value to your directive using the attribute name `ng-model`?

Comment: As an alternative you might want to check out the angular-ui datepicker library. The problem is already solved for you and leverages the same technologies.